# selecting rows that contain certain text for the column of data type dictionary in Presto

Tags: presto

I have a table which has multiple columns with 20 million rows. I am only interested in the rows that has a string "robot" for the column global which is of datatype dictionary in presto Db. I have tried map functions and array functions but couldn't find anything on internet.

My row looks like the following

Column name "global"

Column Value

```
{IS_ROBOT=false, field2=value, ROBOT=false, v_DA_E=, v_DA_T=Internet, 
v_DA_F=Explorer, v_DA_VER=11}
```

Please note that not every row contains ROBOT key regex. The goal is to get the rows that contain that regex as key

edit
datatype is `map<string,string>`

Comment: The phrase "datatype dictionary" doesn't have a meaning in Presto.  Is your column a `VARCHAR` containing a JSON map, or is your column a `MAP<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>`?  If it is JSON, you can use JSON functions or just regular expressions to find the text.  If it is a map, I'd use something like `global['ROBOT'] is not null`.

Comment: Apologies data type is map<string,string>. 
And please note robot is part of the key I am looking for . 
For example key could be one is_robot ,V_robot or something_robot_something.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to combine

- `map_keys` https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_keys
- with array `reduce` https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce
- with lambda string matching

Like:

```
reduce(
    map_keys(your_map),
    false,
    (acc, el) -> acc OR el ILIKE '%robot%',
    acc -> acc)
```

Comment: so how would this function be used in conjunction with the whole database. I have to read from a table name "re" which has multiple columns including global which is one of the columns.  Logically the function makes perfect sense. Thank you